# Bound on the sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, expected-value, binomial-theorem

Let $m \in N$. How to bound from above and below the following sum:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}a^k b^{n-k}k^m
$$

(I know that $\sum_{k\geq 0}{n \choose k}a^k b^{n-k}=(a+b)^n$, but what happened when under summation we multiply by extra $k^m$?)

Comment: You are right, -the power of (a+b) is n. But the sum in the question is correct. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$S_m=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^m a^k*b^{n-k}$$
By binomial theorem we havr
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{m} a^k b^{n-k}$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $a$ we can get
$$S_1=an(a+b)^{n-1}$$
Again d.w.r.t. a, we get
$$S_2=an(a+b)^{n-2}(an+b)$$
Next d.w.r.t $a$ gives
$$S_3=an(a+b)^{n-3}[a^2 n^2+3abn+b^2-ab]$$
Next, we get
$$S_4=an(a+b)^{n-4} P_3(n),$$
where $P_3(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.
A compact general result is difficult to come by.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I am really wanted. I know that the general result is hard to get, that is why I am interested in the upper bound of this sum.